# Changing series colors in HTML5 Builder MChart (teechart)

Tags: php, colors, teechart, html5builder

How do you change the colors of a series for the **MChart** component in Embarcadero's **HTML5 Builder** (Embarcadero® HTML5 Builder Version  5.1.167.137)? In my server mobile application, I use the code below to populate a chart from a DB with a parameter's values. I also create yellow low and high limit lines and red low and high limit lines. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to change the yellow and red series so that they are actually yellow and red.

Create a Server Mobile application, drop an MChart on the form, in the page OnShow event, use this code:

```
function MPage5Show($sender, $params)
{
    // set up y-axis from 0 to 100
    $this->MChart1->Axes->Left->Automatic=false;
    $this->MChart1->Axes->Left->Minimum=0;
    $this->MChart1->Axes->Left->Maximum=100;

    $yellowLoValues = array();
    $yellowHiValues = array();
    $redLoValues = array();
    $redHiValues = array();
    $values = array();
    // yellow low and hi limits
    $ylo=30;
    $yhi=70;
    // red low and hi limits
    $rlo=20;
    $rhi=80;

    for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
        // generate random values, " Y, X "
        array_unshift($values, rand(0,100).','.$i);
        $yellowLoValues[] = $ylo;
        $yellowHiValues[] = $yhi;
        $redLoValues[] = $rlo;
        $redHiValues[] = $rhi;
    }
    // MChart1->Data takes array with values as "Y,X"
    $this->MChart1->Data = $values;

    $series1=$this->MChart1->addSeries(new TeeLine($this));
    $series1->ColorEach = ceNo;
    $series1->Values=$yellowLoValues;
    $series1->Title="Yellow Low Limit";

    $series1=$this->MChart1->addSeries(new TeeLine($this));
    $series1->ColorEach = ceNo;
    $series1->Values=$yellowHiValues;
    $series1->Title="Yellow High Limit";

    $series1=$this->MChart1->addSeries(new TeeLine($this));
    $series1->ColorEach = ceNo;
    $series1->Values=$redLoValues;
    $series1->Title="Red Low Limit";

    $series1=$this->MChart1->addSeries(new TeeLine($this));
    $series1->ColorEach = ceNo;
    $series1->Values=$redHiValues;
    $series1->Title="Red High Limit";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `$series1->Color = 'red';`? If you still find problems with it, please arrange a simple example project we can run as-is to reproduce the problem here.

Comment: @Yeray, If I try '$series1->Color = "red";' I get the following error: Trying to access non-existant property TeeLine->Color in unit5.php, line 105.